# Comparing vectors

Tags: optimization, r, vector

I am new to R and am trying to find a better solution for accomplishing this fairly simple task efficiently.

I have a `data.frame` `M` with `100,000` lines (and many columns, out of which 2 columns are relevant to this problem, I'll call it `M1`, `M2`). I have another `data.frame` where column `V1` with about 10,000 elements is essential to this task. My task is this:

For each of the element in `V1`, find where does it occur in `M2` and pull out the corresponding `M1`. I am able to do this using for-loop and it is terribly slow! I am used to Matlab and Perl and this is taking for EVER in R! Surely there's a better way. I would appreciate any valuable suggestions in accomplishing this task...

```
for (x in c(1:length(V$V1)) {  
    start[x] = M$M1[M$M2 == V$V1[x]]  
}
```

There is only 1 element that will match, and so I can use the logical statement to directly get the element in start vector. How can I *vectorize* this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is another solution using the same example by @aix.

`M[match(V$V1, M$M2),]`

To benchmark performance, we can use the R package `rbenchmark`.

```
library(rbenchmark)
f_ramnath = function() M[match(V$V1, M$M2),]
f_aix = function() merge(V, M, by.x='V1', by.y='M2', sort=F)
f_chase = function() M[M$M2 %in% V$V1,] # modified to return full data frame

benchmark(f_ramnath(), f_aix(), f_chase(), replications = 10000)
     test replications elapsed relative
2     f_aix()        10000  12.907 7.068456
3   f_chase()        10000   2.010 1.100767
1 f_ramnath()        10000   1.826 1.000000
```

Comment: `%in%` should perform in a similar fashion to `match` as it is just a wrapper around `match`

Comment: @chase. i tried your solution, and expected `%in%` to perform the same way as `match`. but when i ran `benchmark`, i was surprised to find that `%in% is 10% slower. wonder what is causing that.

Comment: @Ramnath - thanks for updating the test. Could it be the difference between the `nomatch` parameter? The default is `nomatch = NA_integer_` and `%in%` uses `nomatch = 0`

Comment: @Chase. I think that might be the explanation. I modified the solution using `match` to use `nomatch = 0` and the performance is similar to `%in%`. Also I ran the benchmarking tests on the dataset you generated and I find that the `match` solution is 10% slower than `%in%`. So there might be something else going on here as well.

Comment: On simulated OP data timings are different: `N <- 100000; n <- 10000; M <- data.frame(M1=sample(seq_len(N)), M2=sample(seq_len(N))); V <- data.frame(V1=sample(seq_len(N),n))`. Chase solution is faster.

Comment: @Marek. I found the same thing that Chase's solution is faster. Look at my last comment. Any ideas why that would be the case?

Answer (score 4):

Another option is to use the `%in%` operator:

```
> set.seed(1)
> M <- data.frame(M1 = sample(1:20, 15, FALSE), M2 = sample(1:20, 15, FALSE))
> V <- data.frame(V1 = sample(1:20, 10, FALSE))
> M$M1[M$M2 %in% V$V1]
[1]  6  8 11  9 19  1  3  5
```

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you're looking for `merge`:

```
> M <- data.frame(M1=c(1,2,3,4,10,3,15), M2=c(15,6,7,8,-1,12,5))
> V <- data.frame(V1=c(-1,12,5,7))
> merge(V, M, by.x='V1', by.y='M2', sort=F)
  V1 M1
1 -1 10
2 12  3
3  5 15
4  7  3
```

If `V$V1` might contain values not present in `M$M2`, you may want to specify `all.x=T`. This will fill in the missing values with NAs instead of omitting them from the result.